# Eslint & Prettier make wrong format on svg

Tags: vue.js, svg, eslint, prettier

I am using eslint & prettier, to format my existing vue project. I can format pretty well for vue file. but the svg files are going wrong by comma

```
;<svg width="27" height="28" viewBox="0 0 27 28" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect y="0.0230103" width="27" height="27" fill="#F06D24"/>
<path d="M12.5896 2.27301L11.1167 5.44461C10.8222 5.52457 10.557 5.65783 10.2919 5.79109L6.78647 4.45848L4.66552 6.37744L6.1384 9.54904C5.99112 9.81556 5.87329 10.0288 5.75545 10.2953L2.25 11.6279V14.2931L5.75545 15.6257C5.87329 15.8922 5.99112 16.1055 6.1384 16.372L4.66552 19.5436L6.78647 21.4625L10.2919 20.1299C10.557 20.2365 10.8222 20.3698 11.1167 20.4764L12.5896 23.648H15.5354L17.0083 20.4764C17.2734 20.3698 17.568 20.2632 17.8331 20.1299L21.3385 21.4625L23.4595 19.5436L21.9866 16.372C22.1044 16.1321 22.2517 15.8656 22.3695 15.6257L25.875 14.2931V11.6279L22.3695 10.2953C22.2812 10.0554 22.1339 9.78891 21.9866 9.54904L23.4595 6.37744L21.3385 4.45848L17.8331 5.79109C17.568 5.68448 17.2734 5.55122 17.0083 5.44461L15.5354 2.27301L12.5896 2.27301ZM14.0625 8.93604C16.5075 8.93604 18.4811 10.7217 18.4811 12.9339C18.4811 15.146 16.5075 16.9317 14.0625 16.9317C11.6175 16.9317 9.64386 15.146 9.64386 12.9339C9.64386 10.7217 11.6175 8.93604 14.0625 8.93604Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

put comma infront of svg code. why it does happen.

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['@nuxtjs', 'plugin:nuxt/recommended', 'plugin:prettier/recommended'],
  plugins: [],
}
```

```
{   
    "endOfLine": "auto", 
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "tabWidth": 2,
}
```